# How to fix transition zoom for images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to display blog posts with a image.

I'm using card-columns from bootstrap 4 and when the user hovers the image it scales it.

The problem is when the transition happens my border radius is set to default then back to 10px. (See top border on hover effect)

Check out my fiddle please: https://jsfiddle.net/feifles/93w7ryko/3/

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 50px;
}

.card {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0;
}

.card img {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.card-columns {
  background-color: green;
}

.zoom {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.zoom img {
  max-width: 100%;
  -moz-transition: all 0.7s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.7s;
}

.zoom:hover img,
.zoom:focus img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-columns">
      <div class="card zoom">
        <img src="https://cdn1.thr.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/scale_crop_768_433/2018/02/star_trek_tv_spock_3_copy_-_h_2018.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card zoom">
        <img src="https://cdn1.thr.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/scale_crop_768_433/2018/02/star_trek_tv_spock_3_copy_-_h_2018.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card zoom">
        <img src="https://cdn1.thr.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/scale_crop_768_433/2018/02/star_trek_tv_spock_3_copy_-_h_2018.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title that wraps to a new line</h5>
          <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bug/Issue seems to be happening only on chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In transition there is some bugs that only available in Google Chrome, so for that there are two useful items of CSS:

```
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
```

`-webkit` prefix is use for Chrome and `-moz` is use for Firefox.

Your updated fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/gp8k0zm4/

Comment: Hi Nisharg! Thank you for your answer! Unfortunatelly I don't fully understand it and can't see the updated fiddle. Could elaborate a little bit more pls?

Comment: glad to help you